# How do you retrieve a date value from a buffer-field in Progress Openedge?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I've got a buffer which contains a mix of data, number and character fields. I am getting the displaying the values of the fields, but for some reason date fields return "?" when I try to add them to a string.

I still get ? even if I do

ASSIGN lvString = lvString + STRING( hField:BUFFER-VALUE ).

I've also tried assigning the BUFFER-VALUE to a local DATE variable, and converting that to a string, but that doesn't work either - still ?.

However if I use the STRING-VALUE attribute, it works fine.

How do I get the value out as a date field, rather than just a string?

Comment: You need to show a more complete code snippet.  This doesn't provide enough information to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that you can use to achieve your needs. One is to use directly the table buffer and the other is to use an `QUERY` handle.

First example using a buffer directly from a table (or a TEMP-TABLE, doesn't matter):

```
DEF VAR dateVar     AS DATE NO-UNDO.

FIND FIRST job NO-LOCK.

dateVar = DATE(BUFFER job:BUFFER-FIELD('dt-job'):BUFFER-VALUE).

MESSAGE dateVar
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
```

Second example using a query handle:

```
DEF VAR dateVar     AS DATE NO-UNDO.

DEF QUERY qrJob FOR job.

OPEN QUERY qrJob FOR EACH job.

QUERY qrJob:GET-FIRST().

dateVar = DATE(QUERY qrJob:GET-BUFFER-HANDLE(1):BUFFER-FIELD('dt-job'):BUFFER-VALUE).

MESSAGE dateVar
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
```

As Tim Kuehn said you can substitute `'dt-job'` by # of field in the query if you know its position inside the query. I could used `BUFFER-FIELD(2)` in substitution of `BUFFER-FIELD('dt-job')` because `dt-job` is the #2 field in my query. Keep in mind that use the `FIELDS` clause in a `FOR EACH` or in an `OPEN QUERY` statement changes the order of fields in query. Generally, for browsers only available the columns fields specified in `FIELDS` section, in order.

These might work for you. It's important to say that `BUFFER-VALUE` always returns a `CHARACTER` data type and because of this you need to use `DATE` statement for data conversion.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this - they key information I was missing is that you can only get a character data-type.

Answer (score 0):

The standard form for getting a data of the field's data type is

```
buffer table-name:buffer-handle:buffer-field("field-name"):buffer-value.
```

for arrays it's:

```
buffer table-name:buffer-handle:buffer-field("field-name"):buffer-value[array-element].
```

You can also substitute a field # for "field-name" to get the buffer field handle.